# MSSQL - join two views on different data types

Tags: sql-server, join, multiple-columns, type-conversion

I have two views and need to join them on two different data types and two columns.

the first join is on:
the one view has a `productlength` field of 0.138, data type varchar.
the other view has a `length` field of 0.138, data type float.

the second join is on:
the one view has a `productwidth` field of 0.025, data type varchar.
the other view has a `width` field of 0.025, data type float.

If I joint the two views on just one join it works(can use either fields).
If I use both joins the join fails and the data is not linked.

My query with join is:

```
SELECT  t1.OrderNum,t2.OrderNumber,t1.Description,
t1.ProductThickness,t2.thickness,t1.ProductWidth,t2.width,t1.ProductLength,t2.length,
t1.Productgrade,t2.grade, t1.OrderQty,t1.ProducedQty,t2.DispatchedQty,t2.DispatchDate

FROM table1 as t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 as t2
on t1.ProductWidth=t2.Width
and t1.ProductLength=t2.Length
```

This join then fails? How can I join these two views on both join conditions and across different data types?

Can I convert the varchar to a float so as to do a like for like conversion?

Thanks as always.

Answer (score 0):

try SQL server convert function

Comment: Can you show an example using the command or link to the official docs?

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm if you are using the correct column names and their values are identical while doing the join. Please look at the following link and confirm if you are trying to do the same thing.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/82da2/1